Is gonorrhea test included for France long stay visa?
Is Gonorrhea test for france long stay visa?

Not routinely, in fact the medical exam doesn't include any in-vitro test. Tuberculosis is diagnosed via X-ray and the rest is routine measurements (sight, heigh, blood pressure) and questions.
I assume you may be prescribed a test if you report symptoms or risky behavior but the exam doesn't primarily aim at screening sexually transmitted diseases, see France Working Visa and Mental Health
